# Vertical LinearLayout with WrapContent width - make children fill it up to widest child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, fill-parent

I want to create vertical `LinearLayout` with couple of `Button` children, where each child has width of widest of them.

However depending on using `MATCH_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT` for children width, I get either `LinearLayout` taking whole screen's width, or `Buttons` not filling `LinearLayout`. Screenshots below (fill/wrap):

[image: fill example]
[image: wrap example]

Example Activity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout mainView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);

    String[] buttonsNames = new String[] { "Short", "Looooooong", "Medium" };
    View buttonsView = getButtonsView(buttonsNames);

    mainView.addView(buttonsView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    setContentView(mainView);
}

private View getButtonsView(String[] buttonNames) {
    LinearLayout buttonsView = new LinearLayout(this);
    buttonsView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    buttonsView.setBackgroundColor(Colors.BLACK);

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonNames.length; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(buttonNames[i]);

        ///////////// HERE LAYS THE PROBLEM //////////

        buttonsView.addView(button, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                //LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // neither of them works
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View redLineDivider = new View(this);
        redLineDivider.setBackgroundColor(Colors.RED);
        buttonsView.addView(redLineDivider, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
    }

    return buttonsView;
}
```

As you can see on second screenshot, red lines actually take whole width without stretching `LinearLayout` - it is because at least one view has set width.

Potential fix I have came up with is to find widest button (with longest text) and make it use `WRAP_CONTENT`, while all the rest use `MATCH_PARENT`, which gives me expected result:

[image: wanted result]

Code:

```
buttonsView.addView(button, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                isLongestText(i) ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

It doesn't feel like elegant solution though - is there any intended mechanism for situation like this, that I am missing out?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You would have to do some internal calculations or if you know which one is to be the longest you could use alignment features of the RelativeLayout structure to try and align them via XML.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the trick:

1. Mention the width of the LinearLayout containing the buttons (buttonsView in your code) as WRAP_CONTENT.
2. Mention the width of each button as MATCH_PARENT

Your program should give you the expected result if you do not include the redLineDivider View. There seems to be some issue with setting the width of redLineDivider. As an alternative you can declare it as a LinearLayout to make your code work perfectly.

```
// View redLineDivider = new View(this);
// Instead declare it as a LinearLayout
LinearLayout redLineDivider = new LinearLayout(this);
```

Hope this will be useful.